# Accessing of Web API response object in another partial view (cshtml / cshtml.cs file) in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, visual-studio-2022

On click of a button will from a partialview 1 below js function will be called and get the data from the controller and will be redirected to another partialview. Since it the controller is in another project and hosted separately, controller is not returning the partialview hence I am redirecting it if the ajax call is success.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(paramObj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (response) {
        var userObject = response.internalObject;
    window.location.href = url2;
    },
    error: function (response, status, error) {
        if (response.responseText != undefined) {
            const obj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            fnShowMessage(obj.DisplayMessage);
        }
    }
```

});

I have the data in "userObject" from the ajax call which needs to be displayed in partialview, but I cannot access it or not sure how to access it.

The assigned value in OnGet() method in "partialview2.cshtml.cs" is able to retain in "partialview2.cshtml" file. But how to get the values which I got from the ajax call in partialview 1 in code behind of partialview 2.

```
public class UserModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public UserObject UserObject { get; set; } = new();
    public void OnGet()
    {
        UserObject.UserName = "man";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to return `JsonResult` in OnGet:

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Test",
                data: JSON.stringify(paramObj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                traditional: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var userObject = response;
                    window.location.href = url2;
                },
                error: function (response, status, error) {
                    if (response.responseText != undefined) {
                        const obj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                        fnShowMessage(obj.DisplayMessage);
                    }
                }
            });
```

OnGet handler:

```
public class UserModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public UserObject UserObject { get; set; } = new();
    public JsonResult OnGet()
    {
        UserObject.UserName = "man";
        return new JsonResult(UserObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the values from the previous partial view's ajax call and assign the value in OnGet() method? Currently UserObject.UserName = "man"; is hardcoded second partial view and returning as JsonResult. (Even without returning as JsonResult I was able to get the value "man" in second partial view (cshtml) file

Comment: I am able to pass through query string parameter from the ajax, but is there any other way ? public JsonResult OnGet(string user)
        {
            UserLoginObject.LoginId = user;
            return new JsonResult(UserLoginObject);
        }